# Affiliate Tracking Program for existing ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, affiliate

I have a requirement for our existing ASP.NET website to have sort of an affiliate tracking service. I am looking for a third party affiliate tracking tool that is easy to integrate to ASP.NET. Any suggestions? open source affiliate tool would be great too but I doubt if there is any.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus Web Development made a custom one for us, it works great and we are able to enhance the functionality of it as necessary.

Comment: A link to their site would have been great.